How to parallelize long-running IO operations in a multi-threaded Python application with asyncio?
I am building a Python application that uses an event loop (via the asyncio library) to listen for tick data from a cryptocurrency exchange via a WebSocket. The tick data comes for various symbols, and I’m putting these ticks into a queue.Queue (which is thread-safe but not asyncio-compatible).
A separate thread, TickProcessor, processes the ticks from the queue and makes decisions about whether costly IO operations need to be executed (such as database queries, writes, or REST API calls). Currently, these IO operations are running in a synchronous manner on the worker thread, which introduces significant delays in processing the tick data due to blocking IO calls.
I would like to parallelize the IO operations to reduce this delay and improve the overall performance. I have thought of two potential solutions, but I’m not sure which one would be the most efficient in terms of resource usage. Here are the options I’m considering:
Use the main event loop: The idea is to use the main event loop (which is handling the WebSocket ticks) to run the costly IO operations. In this setup, the processing thread will no longer execute IO tasks directly but will return to the event loop, which will handle the IO operations asynchronously.
Start a separate thread with its own event loop: Another option is to create a new thread, which will start a new event loop to handle the IO operations asynchronously using asyncio. This way, I would effectively have three threads: one for receiving the tick data, one for processing, and one with an event loop running for async IO operations.
Key constraints:
I don't want to refactor the entire application to be fully asynchronous, as this would be too costly and time-consuming. I have working synchronous code that needs to run in order and cannot be easily changed. I don’t mind if certain tasks (like IO operations) wait on a different thread while execution continues on the main thread and processing thread.
Which approach would be more resource-efficient, and what are the advantages and disadvantages of each? Is there any other better solution that I might be missing?

There shouldn't be any difference between running a new eventloop on a thread or pushing async IO back to the first thread because python can only run one thread anyway, the only thing that can happen in parallel is filling the buffers which takes almost no time

If you are unsure, try POC'ing both of them, the you can test them with the same data and do an in-depth comparison based on a level playing field.
